# IDA Pro: How to change segment register value

Tags: ida, assembly, android, arm, section

For a specific Android library that I have loaded into IDA, I want to switch the THUMB/ARM mode to ARM, no matter the consequences that this is going to have to the code. Is there a way to efficiently do this in one go in IDA ?

So far I found out that I can do it by setting a default segment register value, but that apparently works only for segments that do not have any set T value (and IDA seems to set a value by default).

I also found out that I can modify the T register for a specific section through the Segment Register Value window (alt+G to open it), which indeed has the effect that I want, but it going to take months to do it one by one to all sections.

Answer (score 1):

The segment register value applies from one change point until the next or end of segment, so you don't have to set it for each function, just once per segment or a contiguous ARM or Thumb chunk is enough. If you have many wrong intermediate changepoints from previous analysis, you can delete them en masse from the "Jump to segment register..." dialog (<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>).